# ActivityThread.java Null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-activity

I am getting a strange exception in few of my devices on production and I am not sure about the cause of this crash. I am attaching my stack trace with screenshots of the crash on FABRIC/Crashlytics

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to destroy activity {com.zotopay.zoto/com.zotopay.zoto.activityviews.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map$Entry.getValue()' on a null object reference
android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:3969)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:754)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map$Entry.getValue()' on a null object reference
android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.isSynced (LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy (Instrumentation.java:1148)
android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:3956)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:3987)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Here is my onDestoryMethod of Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        clearHandlerCallbacks(activityDataHandler);
        clearHandlerCallbacks(statusColorHandler);
    }

public void clearHandlerCallbacks(Handler handler) {
        if (Common.nonNull(handler))
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
```

Can anyone please have a look if the same has happened to you too and help me debug the issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you add onDestroy method in your DashboardActivity here?

Comment: @sontruongit edited - added onDestroy method

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `super.onDestroy()` before calling another method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  clearHandlerCallbacks(activityDataHandler);
  clearHandlerCallbacks(statusColorHandler);
}
```

it should be like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  clearHandlerCallbacks(activityDataHandler);
  clearHandlerCallbacks(statusColorHandler);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

It is because your activity could be already finished after you're calling `super.onDestroy()`. For more details, please take a look at [`onDestroy()`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L1925) code.

Comment: It may help but actual crash is in LifecyclerRegistry class if you can see my stack trace @ישו אוהב אותך

Comment: @GauravArora any solution to this?