# Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map$Entry.getValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am facing the following problem in my application and have no idea how is it produced or resolved. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map$Entry.getValue()' on a null object reference
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.isSynced(LifecycleRegistry.java:146)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:323)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:137)
   at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:123)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2396)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1467)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3251)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:3215)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:217)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:509)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:498)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:171)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7377)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3763)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3828)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1746)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

**Edit:** Following is the resume method of Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateParams();
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
        if (addButtonClicked) {
            addButtonClicked = false;
            refreshData();
        }
        if (isRestarted) {
            isRestarted = false;
            if (adapter != null && adapter.getFragmentAtPosition(0) != null && (adapter.getFragmentAtPosition(0).isAdded() || !adapter.getFragmentAtPosition(0).isDetached())) {
                ((ListFragment) adapter.getFragmentAtPosition(0)).searchList("");
            }
        }
        checkAndUpdateOnTabs();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the `onResume()` method for this activity? I'm not sure if this is a normal NPE or not.

Comment: Also is this only happening on a specific OS version?

Comment: I have edited question with onResume().. And it isn't happering specific OS.

Comment: in which line app is crashing?

Comment: @RashpalSingh According to the stacktrace it's happening within Android's internal lifecycle handling inside `handleResumeActivity()`, which is probably triggered by `super.onResume()`, so this isn't a normal NullPointerException.

Comment: Are you overriding any other lifecycle methods (e.g. `onCreate()`, `onPause()` etc)

Comment: mObserverMap.newest() is null in LifecycleRegistry.. It is happening in 1 of the fragments in viewpager in activity.

Comment: Are you using the `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions` library?

Comment: yes i am using android.arch.lifecycle:extensions

Comment: Which version? I've found [this bug request on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/430)  and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933725/activitythread-java-null-pointer-exception).

Comment: i am using 1.1.0. The issue in bug is exactly the same exception as mine.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs in lifecycle-extensions have been deprecated. Instead, add dependencies for the specific Lifecycle artifacts you need.

```
 lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

    // Annotation processor
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version"
```